# When should I use enumerations stored in the database and when an enum in the code?

Tags: c#

What is the best way to store enumerations? 
For example, I have an entity Person that has a property Sex. The first option that I can think of is a table that stores the enumeration values and names (1 is for Male and 2 is for Female for example) and then in the Person table to store the int values. The second option is to have an enumeration in the code with a corresponding int values and store in the Person table the int values. The last option is to have again enumeration in the code and store the string value. For example, Person with sex 'Male'.

Which approach is better and when?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enums in code are cool and handy, but you can break your database-integrity when changing the enum.

So in general: use an enum in the database when relational integrity is needed. We use an explicit mapped enum in code to deal with this; and enforce integrity in database. Like:

```
| Id | Value  |
---------------
| 1  | Male   |
| 2  | Female |

// FK from the table above to the table containing all your data, and in code:

enum Gender { Male = 1, Female = 2 }
```

**When to use an enum only in code?**
F.e. Bitmasking! So you can store a bunch of settings that only make sense in your application efficiently in your database. Integrity doesn't really care, because the database doesn't have anything to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular example, gender will always be either Male or Female, so making the database carry that static detail is not very beneficial.

But there are some enumerations that are more dynamic, like a store with enumerations Visa and Mastercard.  May be later they will have to add Discover and Amex, at which point a database enumeration is more useful, given that you handle it in the code dynamically as well.

Answer (score 1):

The third option (store string values) is the worst: you need then to convert between the string and the enum. Storing the enum as int is better, as an enum is basically an int itself, so the cast back and forth is cheap.

Whether to store a lookup in the database would depend on what you want to do in the database: having a foreign key reference to that table will ensure that you only store correct values. But you could also decide that your program will always store a correct value, as that comes from your enum.

Answer (score 1):

I would use both. You should in any way put constraints on your database so you cannot enter any invalid values. If you don't, you will be able to insert invalid values from your program or any other (future) programmes that may use the same database.

You can indeed use a table containing all genders, because that would allow for a foreign key constraint, thus enforcing correct data. Also you can easily extend the table with extra values, although that might not be that useful in case of gender.

But I could also understand if one would want to make it a character(1) field that can contain M, F and maybe some other values representing unknown, none, both (depending on the species stored in the database).

But after that, it may still be convenient to create an enumeration in code as well, which you can use to easily translate those database values. You wouldn't want to use the value '2' in an expession if you actually mean 'female', so you will want to use an enumeration or at least some constants that map -directly or indirectly, because abstraction is the key in database development- to the actual values in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both, but they should be stored in the database. If you're using Visual Studio, you could create a custom T4 (Text Template Transformation Toolkit) template (a .tt file). This will allow you to actually create classes / enums directly from what you have stored in the database. You'll gain the ability to right-click on that tt file, select 'Run custom tool' and have your c# file update from what you have stored in your database.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a chance that the data is going to be needed by some other application, reporting system etc, store the data in the database.

Answer (score 0):

A database enumeration is definitely more useful if use constraints properly.

```
Person
Name   |Age   |Gender |FK_Country_ID|
-------|------|-------|-------------|
varchar|int   |bit    |int          |

Country
CountryID|Country|
---------|-------|
int      |varchar|

Person 0.* ----- 1 Country
```

A **foreign key constraint** will ensure that your data is valid upon insert or update within the database. A hardcoded enumeration will force you to recompile your code later on. It is better practice to read the values for the foreign keys and provide a dynamic look up.